# How can I add a synchronized java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am creatig a program that calculates a predetermined integral with multiple threads using the trap method the result should be 3.1416.......

But I need to add a synchronized function for it to come out. if not I just end up with an orgy of threads?

**UPDATE:**

So in proceso function I'm creating an array of threads that enter class Acumular and starts doing the operation. the problem is that they need to enter on by on that way they will not interrupt the other one and the calculation will be the expected.

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
/**
 *
 * @author GV
 */
public class Examen2 {
    public double sumas = 0.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Examen2 obj = new Examen2();
            obj.proceso();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

    public void proceso () {
        double x = 0.0;
        Acumular thr[];
        thr = new Acumular[4];
        try {
            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                thr[i] = new Acumular(x, x+=.25, .00001);
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                thr[i].start();
            }
            for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                thr[i].join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

        double resultado = sumas*4;
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }

    class Acumular extends Thread {
        private final double x1, x2, paso;

        public Acumular (double a, double b, double p) {
            paso = p;
            x1 = a;
            x2 = b;
        } 
        @Override
        public void run() {
             for (double i = x1; i < x2; i += paso){
                 sumas +=(f(i) + f(i)) * (paso / 2);
             }
        }
        public double f(double x) {
            return sqrt( 1.0 - x*x );
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want someone else to google search for you?

Comment: not sure how to implement it in my code

Comment: If you're going to get any help from here, then you'll need to provide a more explicit description of your problem.  What is an "orgy of threads"?  Why is it bad?  How do you know that it happened?  What would you rather have happen instead? And, if "add a synchronized function" will make it "come out", then what's holding you back?

Comment: That empty `catch` block in your `main(...)` routine is a Bad Idea.  It will prevent you from seeing the message and stack trace if your program terminates on an exception.  That's throwing away information that could have helped you figure out what happened if things go wrong.

Comment: There's no reason why those four threads need to write the shared `sumas`.  Have each thread calculate its own private sum, and then have the main thread add those four sums together at the end after it has joined the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

Your threads are all writing to one shared field *sumas*.

Guess what happens when multiple threads work on shared data without any controls?!

So you have to make sure that your threads can work independently. For example by giving each thread its own suma... Which you could add up in the end when all of the threads finished their work.

One easy way would be to provide a synchronized method like "addToSuma" which your threads would be calling instead of doing += on the field directly.

Comment: exactly!! how do I control them. the point of my program is to make all threads work on the same file in a controlled way

Comment: See my update. But again: the best solution would be to make those threads completely independent by having ONE suma PER thread!